# Programmatically Binding Button Properties to an Indexer Object

Tags: c#, binding, indexer

I'm trying to bind the content properties of programmatically generated buttons to an indexer object.
My indexer object looks like this:

```cs
internal class Indexer
{
    private int[,] cells;//values from 0 to gridSize^2

    public int this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return cells[x, y]; }
    }

    public Indexer(int gridSize)
    {
        cells = new int[gridSize, gridSize];

        FillCells(gridSize);
    }

    private void FillCells(int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                cells[i, j] = i * size + j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Buttons and bindings are created inside two nested for loops and added to a uniform grid.
As a test I bound all of the Button.Content properties to a singular property like this:

```cs
                Button myButton = new Button()
                mazeWindow.XAML_Grid.Children.Add(myButton);

                Binding myBinding = new Binding();
                myBinding.Source = this;
                myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("GridSize");
                myButton.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, myBinding);
```

And that seems to work fine. However I've been unable to figure out how to modify the binding code so that my button contents would be bound to individual cells in my indexer.
Since PropertyPath constructor can be overloaded with path parameters I assumed I could pass my indexer object
and two integers as parameters to set the binding like so:

```cs
                myBinding.Source = this.indexerObject;
                myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Indexer",i,j);
```

But this results in BindingExpression path error: 'Indexer' property not found on 'object' ''Indexer'

I assume there must be something about indexers that I dont understand (never used them before) or my approach to this problem is somehow flawed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify indexes in the path string using old good string formatter (interpolated string same good):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        var myButton = new Button();
        grid.Children.Add(myButton);
        myButton.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, i);
        myButton.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, j);
        Binding myBinding = new Binding($"GridSize[{i},{j}]") { Source = this };
        myButton.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, myBinding);
    }
```

I've used 10x10 grid filled with buttons adding corresponding number of row/column definitions to xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.
Turns out my indexer class was actually missing a line:

```
    [IndexerName("SomeIndexerName")]
    public int this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return cells[x, y]; }
    }
```

After that I dropped the extra PropertyPath parameters and simply used:

```
                myBinding.Source = this.indexerObject;
                myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath($"SomeIndexerName[{i},{j}]");
```

And it worked!